# Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger Icon Not Showing Up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this navbar with the hamburger icon i'm trying to use with bootstrap. I'm trying to use an example i found online but when i run it the hamburger icon is missing and the drop menu is already expanded, which it shouldn't, by default it should be collapsed. Also the title which in my case right now is, WebSiteName, is on the right side of the navbar but in the example i'm going off it's on the left side. Below is the the html code i'm using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The hamburger icon seems to be displayed (on small screens). You are using a dropdown class, but your code doesn’t have the link code to act as a button to open and close the dropdown. Is the code below is what you’re trying to do?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```